# How to add extra fields to Firebase auth? Age & Gender

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So far I'm really impressed with **`Firebase`**. But I would like to know how would I go about customizing my user email authentication. I would like to add the following fields: ***Age*** and ***Gender*** for users to fill out when registering.

here's my SignUpActivity.java.

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword, signupInputUsername, signupInputAge;
private Button btnLinkLogin, btnSignUp, btnResetPassword;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private Spinner sexSpinner;
String defaultTextForSpinner = "Sex";
String[] arrayForSpinner = {"Male", "Female"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

    //Get Firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_email);
    signupInputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_username);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_password);
    signupInputAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_birthday);
    sexSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    sexSpinner.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_row, arrayForSpinner, defaultTextForSpinner));

    btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp2);
    btnLinkLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnorlogin);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_birthday);


    edittext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //To show current date in the datepicker
            Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            int mYear = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mMonth = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int mDay = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog mDatePicker=new DatePickerDialog(SignUpActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /*      Your code   to get date and time    */
                }
            },mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            mDatePicker.setTitle("Select birthday");
            mDatePicker.show();  }
    });


    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (password.length() < 6) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //create user
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(SignUpActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context context;
    String[] objects;
    String firstElement;
    boolean isFirstTime;

    public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects, String defaultText) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
        this.isFirstTime = true;
        setDefaultText(defaultText);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(isFirstTime) {
            objects[0] = firstElement;
            isFirstTime = false;
        }
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public void setDefaultText(String defaultText) {
        this.firstElement = objects[0];
        objects[0] = defaultText;
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, parent, false);
        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinner_text);
        label.setText(objects[position]);

        return row;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you are using Firebase authentication with user and password, the only data that you can get after authentication  is that data that you get from [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) object. As you probably see, there also a couple of methods that can help you get the data easier, like: `getEmail()`, `getDisplayName()`, `getPhotoUrl()` and so on.

Unfortunately, you cannot add additional data like `age` and `gender` to the `FirebaseUser` object. If you want to add additional data, you need to create a model class for your user and then store it in your Firebase database.

You model class should look like this:

```
public class User {
    String name, gender, emailAddress;
    int age;

    public User(String name, String gender, String emailAddress, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

    public String getGender() {return gender;}
    public void setGender(String gender) {this.gender = gender;}

    public String getEmailAddress() {return emailAddress;}
    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {this.emailAddress = emailAddress;}

    public int getAge() {return age;}
    public void setAge(int age) {this.age = age;}
}
```

Comment: What about using the [setDisplayName](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder#public-userprofilechangerequest.builder-setdisplayname-string-displayname) method to store custom fields as a JSON Object like this example `{"display_name": "User 1", "age": 25, "gender": "Male", "points": 5371}`? Is it good practice? And what is the maximum of characters can I store inside display_name?

Comment: @TahaSami That's not even possible. setDisplayName()` method takes an argument of type String. You cannot call that method with a JSON object.

Comment: But I can convert JSON Object as String type. By the way, I tried this by myself and when I sort long content inside the display name field the result will be null, I don't know where can I store the custom fields, I don't want to use Firestore because there is a lot of scenarios like connection failure also there is no support transaction between Firestore and Auth. I don't know why the Firebase team does not add a new field to Auth and this field will be for custom fields. I don't want to use Firebase Functions because it may fail also. Any other solutions?

Comment: @TahaSami Using an extra step in which you can convert a JSON object into a String might be possible. I'm not aware of any other solutions. However, without seeing your code, I cannot say why you got null. If you are looking for a solution, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you. Besides that, send that as a request directly to the Firebase team. Maybe it will implement such functionality at one point in time.

Comment: Okay, I appreciate your help, Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

In general, after sign up, you can create a node tree for user like picture.
Then, you can get the info with user key that can get by calling FirebaseUser.
I hope it helps. If you have any questions, let me know.[image: an example]

Comment: is users a custom table?

Comment: Yes, it is @VaibS

Answer (score 1):

After signing up a new user you will receive a generated uuid of the user from Firebase, that's when you need to take the uuid and create a new user entry in your Firestore repository/Realtime database with the uuid that you were provided and the additional informations.